# How to make AutoCompleteText full screen (Android)

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

I want to make a autocompletetextview to full screen view when it was clicked and when a option is clicked then it back to it's normal view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it , create new activity with edit text and recycleView and when select item return result to previous activity
at current activity contain design
do select work space make it `android:focusable="false"` use event onClickListner to open newActivity